# Why there's no Nullable-Generic Methods? which accept both references and value types

Tags: c#, .net, generics, nullable, c#-7.3

This Works

```
    public static T? Read<T>(object value) where T : struct
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
```

But this doesn't work:

> Error CS8370  Feature 'nullable reference types' are not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater.

```
   public static T? Read<T>(object value)
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
```

I am curious about the error or feature I have searched but nothing found.

I may be **deleted** the question if not related. so please inform me of doing that.

Comment: Even with C# 8 this wouldn't be feasible - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58852272 for the reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's mean it's not working? and why it implemented. reference types i mean why they need the "?" its already allow null. or its just for design or fun.

Comment: This question is about trying to write a method that returns a nullable form of an arbitrary type parameter. The question I linked to is also about that. That should in **no way** be taken as a statement that nullable reference types are a bad idea. This is just a limitation. In terms of "why ? is necessary" is a much broader question - I suggest you read more about nullable reference types in general. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

Comment: @deveton: There is apparently a switch that turns non-nullable for reference types on by default. | It is kinda like a readonly or out - a compiler hint for what should/should not happen to this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nullable refrence types are only being added with [C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#nullable-reference-types). You are building with C# 7.3.

The naming is a bit confusing, however. Nullable structs/value types make sense. Because normally they are not nullable.

But all reference types are inhrently nullable. It seems actually about changing that rule a bit, without implicitly making all references types non-nullable (like value types).

Comment: "And even with that, I am not sure what they are even there for. Reference types are inherently nullable, after all." And that's what changes in C# 8 when you have nullable reference types turned on. A variable of type `string` goes from nullable (before C# 8, or with NRT turned off) to "shouldn't be null, compiler will warn you if it looks like it might be" with NRT turned on, for example.