# Nullable template field

Tags: c#

I have found this kind of code in a C# application:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T:class
{
    public T? field1 { get; set; }
}
```

I do not understand why but I have this error on my development environment:

> [CS8627] A nullable type parameter must be known to be a value type or non-nullable reference type. Consider adding a 'class', 'struct', or type constraint.

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you use constraint `where T : class`? The error occurs because of this constraint. Only struct types can be nullable. Reference types (specified by the constraint `where T : class`) cannot be nullable (prior to `C#8`).

Comment: This answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/58852480/10983940

Comment: same problem if i remove "where T : class"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nullable (`?`) operator is used to assign `null` to valuetyped objects. Normally you cannot assign `null` to a `valuetyped` data type such as `int`, `long`, `DateTime` etc.

```
MyClass<T> where T:class
```

But in your case, you are explicitly saying your generic type (`T`) can only be a `class`. Classes are always reference typed and it can be assigned to null natively. This is the reason it showing error and you dont need to mark it as nullable

> This will compile since `T` is always a `struct` and structs are valuetyped

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : struct
{
    public T? field1 { get; set; }
}
```

> This will not compile since the compiler doesn't know whether `T` can be a `class` too

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T? field1 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine only of you remove the interrogation point from the T? Property.
A class is nullable by default