# Why is "default" different from "null" when assigning to a nullable type constrained by notnull?

Tags: c#, generics, non-nullable

Consider this minimal-ish example:

```
class A<T> where T : notnull
{
    public T? Item; // OK!
    public T? Something() => default; // OK!
    public void Meow(ref T? thing1, out T? thing2) { thing2 = default; } // OK!
    void Something(A<T>? other)
    {
        // OK!
        Item = other is null ? default : other.Item;

        // Error CS0403 : Cannot convert null to type parameter 'T' because it could be a non-nullable value type. Consider using 'default(T)' instead.
        Item = other is null ? null : other.Item;

        // Error CS8978 :  'T' cannot be made nullable.
        Item = other?.Item;
        Item = other?.Item ?? default;
        var x = other?.Item;
    }
    void Weird<U>(A<U>? other) where U : unmanaged
    {
        // OK!
        var x = other?.Item;
    }
    void Weird2<U>(A<U>? other) where U : class
    {
        // OK!
        var x = other?.Item;
    }
    void Weird3<U>(A<U>? other) where U : struct
    {
        // OK!
        var x = other?.Item;
    }
}
```

`T` is notnull

`T?` is either `T` or `null` ... isn't it?  In what case would that NOT be true?

If `T` is `struct` then `Item` is `Nullable<T>`, which can be assigned by `null`

If `T` is `class` then 'Item' is simply `T?` which also can be assigned by `null`

I even made `T` unmanaged just to double check (it should be a subset of `struct`), and that can be assigned by `null`

...

*So what type `T` exists such that `T?` could not hold the value `null`?*

... I'm also not quite sure I'm even asking the right question ... My real question is "Why doesn't it work!!?!?!" :)

Note: A similar question was properly answered here: [C#'s can't make `notnull` type nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58852272/cs-cant-make-notnull-type-nullable) ... but that answer is applicable for C# 8 ... as of C# 9 and above, it's no longer the case

I'll also point out docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters ... which basically say that `notnull` means class/struct

...

Edit (afterthought): If it's an IL issue (that the IL needs to know whether it's a a nullable reference type or Nullable) ... Then why does `default` work and `null` doesn't?  Clearly *SOME* version of IL works, so it's just a language deficiency/quirk?

Comment: Why do you think there are different rules in C# 9.0? None of the links provides evidence for that

Comment: Set your csproj to LangVersion 8.0 and try out Jon Skeet's example (from the first link).  The compiler will tell you it won't work unless you use 9.0 or higher.

Answer (score 3):

Welp, I'm posting an answer (since nobody else did), after posting this as a bug here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/59805

The answer is that `T?` is not `int?` when `T` is an `int`.  `T?` is simply `int`.

Which is nuts :)

It's even weirder because if you tell the compiler that `T` is a `struct`, then suddenly `T?` *is* `int?` when `T` is an `int`.

Weird.  But okay.  So be it.

Comment: The sad part of the story is: `That's just not how the actual runtime works. This was determined back when generics were done 17 years ago.`. Probably we could ask @EricLippert for the details why it has been done that way. Yet another small peeble to the pond, telling us how inferior C# generics are to C++ templates. Gosh, I sometimes miss templates so much :(